# Programmatically get msbuild's SolutionName in c#

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

My project file has this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <SolutionName>Foo</SolutionName>
  <AssemblyName>$(SolutionName).$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I can get `AssemblyName` programmatically using `GetType().Assembly.GetName().Name`.

Is it possible to get `SolutionName`?

Comment: Why not simply write the name as a string Resource in your project and access it by 'Properties.SolutionName' (assuming you name the Resource 'SolutionName')? Sure, you would have to maintain this resource manually, but the name of the solution usually not changes too often. For a multiproject solution you may put the name in a core project and make the Resources public in order to access from other projects in your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - not really. The solution file is simply an organization for visual studio. It is not embedded in the built binaries.

What you maybe could do as a workaround is get the solution name in msbuild, and then write it to a file.

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160

`$(SolutionName)`   The base name of the solution. Defined only when building a solution in the IDE.